# ANOVA degrees of freedom is incorrect

Tags: r, anova

The results of my ANOVA are as follows,

```
mnn=aov(gy~gen+rep, data=my)
summary(mnn)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
gen          6 1923.1   320.5  31.206 5.42e-07 ***
rep          1    7.1     7.1   0.695    0.419    
Residuals   13  133.5    10.3
```

Why it is showing only **1** df for `rep` instead of **2** when the number of levels of rep are **3** in the data.

Here is my sample dataset,

```html
   gen rep gy  sy
1    a   1 40  95
2    b   1 50 120
3    c   1 55 120
4    d   1 60 140
5    e   1 40 110
6    f   1 50 125
7    g   1 65 145
8    a   2 35 100
9    b   2 50 125
10   c   2 59 130
11   d   2 65 150
12   e   2 40 110
13   f   2 55 130
14   g   2 60 145
15   a   3 40 100
16   b   3 50 120
17   c   3 50 130
18   d   3 65 145
19   e   3 40 115
20   f   3 55 130
21   g   3 70 155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably intended to treat `rep` as a *categorical* predictor. Because the values of `rep` in your data set are numeric (1,2,3), R will assume that `rep` is a continuous predictor (and hence you are doing a form of ANCOVA rather than a two-way ANOVA). In this case you have to explicitly specify that the variable is categorical by transforming it with `factor()`, either within the data set:

```
my$rep <- factor(my$rep)
```

or on the fly during your `aov()` call:

```
aov(gy~gen+factor(rep), data=my)
```